# Laravel | Как передать в класс у которого метод __invoke

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Такой код выдаст ошибку "Call to undefined method App\Services\Goods\Store::class()" 
Тут я пытаюсь вызвать класс у которого "главный" метод __invoke, только в него нужно передать $request.
 Как это можно сделать?

```
    public function GoodsStore($request) {
       return Store::class($request);
    }
```

Comment: Так вы посмотрите в документацию по методу __invoke  когда он вызывается.... там же всё написано...Сейчас не выполняется требования для вызова..

Comment: Также посмотрите в документацию, что конкретно возвращает `::class`

Comment: `return (new Store)($request);` [The __invoke() method is called when a script tries to call an object as a function.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke)  p.s. лучше передавать весь объект $request в сервисы, возвращайте только то, что нужно, напр. `$request->only(['param1', 'param2'])`